# Can't access to a NSString of another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nsstring

I have a problem obtaining the value of a `NSString`, named `latitudeString` from another class. Currently I have two view controllers, the first has users coordinates and the second has a `MKMapView` which show the current user position on a map. The problem is that I want the pin to show the coordinates of the user position in his subtitle but I can't obtain the value of `latitudeString` and Xcode gives me this error:

```
Property 'latitudeString' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'
```

Here's the code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocation          *newLocation;
    NSString            *latitudeString;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager                 *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString                          *latitudeString;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize latitudeString;

CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

@end
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{

}

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()
{
    ViewController              *firstViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController                *firstViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView            *mapView;

@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize firstViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.userLocation.title = @"Posizione attuale";
    self.mapView.userLocation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstViewController.latitudeString]; // ERROR

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks.

### Update #1

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocation          *newLocation;
    NSString            *latitudeString;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager                 *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    self->latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

@end
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    ViewController              *firstViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController                *firstViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView            *mapView;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.userLocation.title = @"Posizione attuale";
    self.mapView.userLocation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstViewController->latitudeString]; // ERROR

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Comment: BTW - the update you just made to your question is inappropriate since the answer was based on the previous code. You should have posted the new code as an update to the question. This was existing answers still make sense.

Comment: Ok I will change the code to the previous one and post the new one as an update, just give me a minute :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `latitudeString` property of `ViewController` is a private property. Only methods of `ViewController` can access it. If you want it to be a public property you need to move the property declaration to the .h file.

BTW - get rid of all of your calls to `@synthesize`. As used, they are obsolete. Also get rid of the ivars you defined for the properties. They are also obsolete.

Try this:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

// A public property
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *latitudeString;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

// A private property
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    // A private instance variable (ivar)
    CLLocation *newLocation;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    self.latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy! But now XCode shows me a different error:"Instance variable 'latitudeString" is protected", how can I solve this?. Thank you for your suggestion too!

Comment: In `ViewController.m, replace uses of `latitudeString` with `self.latitudeString`. Use the property you have declared. If that isn't the issue, update your question with your updated `ViewController.h`.

Comment: Ok give me one minute to update the code in my question. I can't rename "latitudeString" to "self.latitudeString" because XCode force me to use "self->latitudeString" instead, is it correct?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code in my question following your suggestion, is it correct now?

Comment: Ok, I've made those changes in my code and XCode doesn't give me an error anymore but when I click on the pin the subtitle show me:"(null)" like the NSSString is "nil" :-/

Comment: In your `MapViewController viewDidLoad` method, is `firstViewController` set?

Comment: Do you mean I have to "alloc" it?. I'm sorry but I'm not very good at this :-/

Comment: You have moved on to a totally separate question. Close this one out since it has been answered. Post a new question to cover your newest issue.

Comment: It's not obsolete. If he wants the ivar to be named exactly `latititudeString`, then he needs to use `@synthesize`.

Comment: @newacct That is true. However, it is a bad idea to do so. The reason that, by default, modern Objective-C generates property ivars with a leading underscore is to avoid confusion between the ivar and the property name. It caused untold issues and lost productivity in the past before ARC when the ivar and property had the same name.

Comment: @rmaddy in class1 i have store  one value to nsstring and trying to access it from other class, but it shows null value. I have create nsstring's outlet as you have suggested.